# What has changed in Java, so that the tutorial example is not accurate any more?

Tags: java, generics

I found this wonderful tutorial on Java generics and wanted to try out the examples and play around a bit for myself. However, I found out that there is a discrepancy between what the tutorial says and what the Java 8 platform is actually doing. Now I am confused. Why is that?

I.e. according to the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html), [the code](https://ideone.com/3YAkYS) should throw a ClassCastException on line 6. But instead, it throws one on line 5, near `n.setData("Hello");` already.

This is the code:

```
class NodeMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
        Node n = mn;            // A raw type - compiler throws an unchecked warning
        n.setData("Hello");
        Integer x = mn.data;    // Causes a ClassCastException to be thrown.
    }
}

class Node<T> {

    public T data;

    public Node(T data) { this.data = data; }

    public void setData(T data) {
        System.out.println("Node.setData");
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {
    public MyNode(Integer data) { super(data); }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: That code **does** throw `ClassCastException` (on the `n.setData("Hello");` line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line 5 `n.setData("Hello");` is in fact calling

```
public void setData(Integer data) {
```

with a **String** argument.

Doing so will always throw that exception (because a String is not an Integer). You see, even when calling the method on the *n* reference; at runtime, the JVM will use the *overridden* method and call `setData(Integer)`.

The problem is that the tutorial isn't exactly clear here. The exception is **not** thrown on line 6, and never was. I think they wanted to explain one thing, and wrote that code to express that idea; but didn't think it through to the end.

Comment: Confirmed the "never was". Tested on Java 5, 6, 7, and 8.

Comment: Yep. It looks like that the bridge method mentioned in the tutorial is actually called and the class cast exception happens right there at `setData((Integer) data);`.

But do you agree that the tutorial is wrong here?

Comment: I'd like to add that in line 5, what is really called is the generated bridge method `MyNode#setData(Object data)`. That methods is the one that overrides `Node#setData(T data)`. The bridge method in its turn calls `MyNode#setData(Integer data)`, and this causes the `ClassCastException`. This can be seen inspecting the generated byte code with `javap`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification @GhostCat.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the clarification. Will improve my answer later on. Or feel free to edit it.